# "WHY" - What part of speech is it? And can it be removed?

Tags: grammar

I wasn't sure how to look this up because I'm not sure the part of speech "why" is in this case, and if it was grammatically correct with or without.

Thanks!!!

E.g.

The exact reason **why** this surname was affixed to them is not entirely clear, except for the fact that they were German.

**vs.**

The exact reason this surname was affixed to them is not entirely clear, except for the fact that they were German.

Comment: "Why" is a relative adverb here, functioning as an adjunct of reason in the relative clause "why this surname was affixed to them". It is optional, as in your second example; alternatively "that" could be used instead of "why".

Comment: Thanks @BillJ, so if they are both correct is it just a matter of style/voice?

Comment: Generally, but not always, the omission of the relative word is found in informal contexts.

Answer (score 1):

The Oxford Living Dictionary has [this entry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/why) in which there is a definition as a **Relative Adverb**

> (with reference to a reason) on account of which; for which.

With example

> ‘the reason why flu jabs need repeating every year is that the virus changes’

This is the same sentence structure as your sentence except that yours modifies, or intensifies, "why" with "exact" but this does not change the function of "why"

The English First website gives [this explanation](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/relative-adverbs/) of relative adverbs which reads

> The relative adverbs where, when & why can be used to join sentences or clauses. They replace the more formal structure of preposition + which used to introduce a relative clause.

It also gives the following example of "why" replacing "for which"

Using "for which"

> Tell me the reason **for which** you came home late.

Using "why"

> Tell me (the reason) **why** you came home late.

So in your case "why" is a relative adverb.

I got the OLD entry by searching for "why define". A dictionary definition is always a good place to start for questions like this.

Comment: thanks @Boldben, but I wasn't clear about your final conclusion. Are both sentences of mine (w and w/o "why") correct?

Comment: @romebot Yes it's fine. However "why" is still implied in the sentence, just not specifically included. We do this quite a lot in English. In fact my answer shows that in "Tell me why you came home" the words "the reason" are implied. This is also (the reason) why we can use phrases like "Look out!" even though they don't contain a subject for the verb. In that case the word "You" is implied.

Comment: I agree that _why_ here is a relative adverb. The _reason for which_ construction is fine when it refers to the whole of the main clause. For example, _He quit his job, the reason for which he did not tell me_ = _He did not tell me the reason for quitting his job_. But for me it sounds 'off' in EF's sentence _Tell me the reason for which you came home late_. At any rate,  each of the three alternatives: omitting the relative altogether, using the relative _why_ or the subordinator _that_ sound much more natural.

Comment: @shoe I understood that EF were using the construction as an explanation of what was going on, not that the version without "why" was preferable. If you follow the link you will see that they have a matrix of comparisons like that explaining the use of all three relative adverbs.

Comment: @BoldBen I wouldn't go along with you. "Why" is not used in fused relative clauses -- in "Tell me [why you came home]" the bracketed element is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question), not a relative clause.

Comment: Thanks. EF's first four 'formal structure' sentences allow the end-position preposition: _the restaurant (which) we met in, the park (which) I used to play at, the day (which) we met on, the year (which) he was born in_. But this doesn't seem to  work for _Tell me the reason for which you came home late_: > _?The reason (which) you came here for_. So, something else is going on in this last example. If I have time I'll pursue the issue since it seems an interesting one. But I'd be interested if others share my opinion about the awkwardness of _Tell me the reason for which you came home late_.

Comment: thanks all for the good discussion.

Comment: There are some contexts where _why_ isn’t even an option and the frightfully clunky _for which_ appears to be the only possibility. This is so at least when _reason_ is determined by _which_, as in “There was an accident on the M1, for which reason I came home late”. Dialectally, I think “There was an accident on the M1, why I came home late” is acceptable (and it’s certainly perfectly normal and grammatical in at least some other Germanic languages), but not in Standard English.